# Declare type object in an oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to declare type object in a package ?

it seems like the one following is not supported in the context the package

```
TYPE xxx AS OBJECT
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. an object type is a database object that must be declared using the CREATE statement. Its similar to a package in that it must have a spec declaration and a body implementation.

Once you've created it, you can then reference it in a package

Comment: Thank you.. is there a way to use heritage on a type declared inside the package only? what type if it is possible?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you want to do? You can't declare and use your own types in a package. Maybe if you post a new question with some example code and a description of what you're trying to achieve?